# Fibonacci program in java

Tags: java

```
public class Fibannoci {


    static int fibo(int fir,int sec){
        int res=0;

        int i=0;
        while(i<10){

            res=fir+sec;
            i++;
            fibo(sec,res);
        }


        return res;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        System.out.println(fibo(1,1));

    }

}
```

This is my Fibonacci program. I am trying to print the number which will come in 10th place. I do not want to see others code online and do. I want to try myself and improve this code so that I get the understanding. Please show me how should I edit this such that I get fibo series of first 10 numbers

Comment: How do I show you what you are missing if you don't want to see it?

Comment: It's currently unclear what you're asking. What do you expect your code to do? Why do you have those expectations? What do you want the code to do? Why doesn't it do it? What has your debugging revealed?

Comment: Use System.out.println to see what is happening in your code

Comment: You're recursively calling `fibo` with no end condition.  I expect you're running into an infinite loop here.  Do you want to calculate this recursively (`fibo` calls itself) or iteratively (using a loop)?  You don't need to do both.

Comment: Please show me how do I correct the code so that I can print first 10 numbers in fibo series

Comment: If you're just looking for the code, there are literally hundreds (at least) of examples and explanations for how to do this a quick google search away.    What, *exactly*, don't you understand about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some problems to fix:

- your print statement takes a single value. That means your `fibo` method needs to return a list of numbers, not a single `int`. Try returning `List<Integer>`
- You are calling `fibo` recursively but doing nothing with the result of the call.
- There's not a lot of reason to call it recursively if you want to return a fixed number of elements. Iteration is probably simpler in that case.
- Get used to using better variable names. With modern IDEs there's no reason to use abbreviations like 'sec' that are ambiguous and hard for a reader to immediately understand.

Answer (score 0):

For your program, you do not need an argument first or second, you just need a variable `n` to have the number of times you want the Fibonacci sequence repeated, then you should just recursively call the method, having the end cases as `if (n==0) return 0;` and `if (n==1) return 1;` The code is below, if you would like to take a look. Hope this helps!

```
public int fibonacci(int n)  {
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if(n == 1)
      return 1;
    else
      return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```